# Вложенность функций

Tags: visual-c++

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Пишу курсовую в Visual C++ 2017, там в функциях через switch/case вызываются другие функции и тд. При запуске консоли несколько функций выполняются, а, когда наступает очередь следующей функции, курсор переходит на следующую строку и все: просто мигает курсор и приходится прерывать всю программу. Скажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема? Если слишком большая вложенность разве не должно показывать какие-нибудь ошибки? Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Телепаты, способные разобраться в проблеме без [минимального примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), сюда заходят редко, так что если вы не хотите ждать ответа на свой вопрос до морковкина заговенья - задайте его так, чтобы можно было ответить, опираясь на конкретный код...

Comment: код слишком большой, не думаю что он уместен, а ситуация следующая: в функции цикл while , в нем оператор swith/case, в каждом case которого функция. В свою очередь у этих функций также есть цикл и switch. На определенном этапе после выбора следующей функции, которую хочу выполнить, происходит ситуация описанная выше. Я в замешательстве.

Comment: Ну, тогда ждите телепатов...

Comment: я полностью понимаю вашу позицию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Пришел телепат.*

На "следующей строке" вызывается функция, которая не возвращается, так как цикл `while` в ней (или в функции, вызываемой в ней) крутится бесконечно. Чтобы в этом убедиться, нажмите кнопку "Пауза".